# Namespace nesting rules

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++17

I'm trying to build an intuition of what kind of scopes nested namespaces create.

**Example 1.** shared "prefix":

```
namespace a::b::c {
   int x = 0;
}
namespace a::b::d {
   int y = c::x + 1; // ok
}
```

**Example 2.** more shared some "prefix":

```
namespace a::b {
    int x = 0;
}

namespace a::b::c {
  int y = x + 1; // ok
}
```

**Example 3.** shared some "prefix" but with a namespace in the middle:

```
namespace a::b::c {
    int x = 0;
}

namespace a::c {
  int y = b::c::x + 1; // ok, 'a' is shared
}
```

**Example 4.** shared some "prefix" but with a namespace in the middle:

```
namespace a::b {
    int x = 0;
}

namespace a::c::b {
  int y1 = x + 1; // ERROR: even though we're nested inside a { b {} }
  int y2 = b::x + 1; // ERROR: even though they both are nested inside 'a' {}
  int y3 = a::b::x + 1; // ok 
}
```

Example 4 is not super clear to me. Is there a simple rule to explain it?

Comment: "A namespace in the middle" is a different namespace. Remember, things in a namespace are different from things in a different namespace, even if they have the same name (that's actually the entire point of namespaces)

Comment: is a::b::c::x really okay? that is strange. Try it on https://godbolt.org/ and it does not work.

Comment: sorry, copy-pasta error. will edit

Comment: When searching for `b` in `b::x` in example 4, the compiler identifies `b` as teh current namespace before considering searching for `b` in a namespace "further up". This namespace does not contain the desired member `x` though.

Comment: I see, so from the comments so far. It keeps looking for the first namespace that matches the current pattern. e.g. `b::` matches `a::c::b::` so it resolve this namespace as this, without further looking for `a::b::`.

Comment: The `b` in the `a::b` namespace is not the same `b` in the `a::c::b` namespace.  Different `b` spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

```
namespace a::c::b {
  int y1 = x + 1; // ERROR: even though we're nested inside a { b {} }
```

The comment is wrong: the nearest common nesting is `a`. The namespace `b` inside `c` is different from the namespace `b` inside `a` even though they have the same name (that's what namespaces are for!)

There's no `x` in `b` (the one we're in), none in `c`, none in `a`, and none in the global scope.

```
  int y2 = b::x + 1; // ERROR: even though they both are nested inside 'a' {}
```

Yes, but `b` finds the namespace `b` inside `c`, not the namespace `b` inside `a`, because it's closer. Then it looks for `x` in that namespace and there isn't one.

```
  int y3 = a::b::x + 1; // ok 
}
```

of course. No surprise there. `a` finds namespace `a` which has a `b` in it which has an `x` in it.